# Use realm and MVVMLight

Tags: xamarin, realm

I use MVVMLight to develop and app in Xamarin. My team uses iOS and Android native, so not Xamarin Forms.

We use Realm to store data in, and want to use MVVMLight to bind data to the UI. We have a `public IRealmCollection<Info> InfoList { get; private set; }`.

The `ObservableCollection<T>` have a `GetController` to bind the data. (https://mallibone.com/post/mvvm-light-ios-uitableview-binding)

Does Realm for Xamarin have something similar so we can bind data to the UI?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately the MVVMLight codebase has a hard requirement on the observable collection being `IList<T>` which is more restricting than the API provided by Realm. The good news is that it's open source, so you can easily make the modifications needed to make it work. You'll need [`ObservableTableViewController`](https://mvvmlight.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#GalaSoft.MvvmLight/GalaSoft.MvvmLight.Platform%20(iOS)/Helpers/ObservableTableViewController.cs) and [`ObservableTableViewSource`](https://mvvmlight.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#GalaSoft.MvvmLight/GalaSoft.MvvmLight.Platform%20(iOS)/Helpers/ObservableTableViewSource.cs). Then just modify all DataSource properties/fields to be `IReadOnlyList<T>` instead of `IList<T>`. Then the `GetController` extension method can be modified to be:

```
public static ObservableTableViewController<TItem> GetController<TItem>(
    this IReadOnlyList<TItem> collection,
    Func<NSString, UITableViewCell> createCellDelegate,
    Action<UITableViewCell, TItem, NSIndexPath> bindCellDelegate,
    string reuseId = null)
{
    return new ObservableTableViewController<TItem>
    {
        DataSource = collection,
        CreateCellDelegate = createCellDelegate,
        BindCellDelegate = bindCellDelegate,
        ReuseId = reuseId,
    };
}
```

Comment: To understand it correct. Do I need to download the MVVMLight codebase and modify it or??

I prefer to use NuGet to keeps my packages updated.

Comment: You can use both. You use NuGet for everything, you just need to download the two classes I linked to and modify those - probably would be a good idea to give them different names to avoid potential confusion. But those will not affect the rest of the codebase or the way you use it.